# Is there a fix for duplicate tabs when creating dynamically?

Tags: tornadofx

I'm trying to dynamically create a tabpane using Tornadofx version 1.7.18 and for some reason the tabs are being duplicated.

I have a configuration file that loads into the application with changeable values so that the program follows the [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) principles, specifically the open-closed principle.
I'm using the Javafx solution for adding tabs by calling `tabpane.tabs.add()` inside of a `forEach` loop.

This is a simplified version of my problem but still shows the issue.

```
class Example: View() {
    private val tabList = List(3) {
        return@List it.toString()
    }

    override val root = tabpane()

    init {
        with(root) {
            tabClosingPolicy = TabPane.TabClosingPolicy.UNAVAILABLE

            tabList.forEach {
                this.tabs.add(
                    tab(it) {
                        label("Hello $it")
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This ends up showing both "0" tabs being shown as selected. The window ends up looking like this on a Windows machine:

```
+----------------+
|icon|    |-|[]|X|
+----------------+
||0|0|1|1|2|2|   |
+----------------+
|Hello 0         |
+----------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you're using the `tab()` builder and then adding the result to the tabs list. Absolutely every builder in TornadoFX automatically adds whatever it creates to it's parent, so you don't ever have to do that manually.

Every builder also returns whatever it builds, so that's why your code even compiles. You can fix your bug simply by removing the surrounding `this.tabs.add()` call, like this:

```
tabList.forEach {
    tab(it) {
        label("Hello $it")
    }
}
```

For completeness, here is the complete root builder using best practices:

```
override val root = tabpane {
    tabClosingPolicy = TabPane.TabClosingPolicy.UNAVAILABLE

    tabList.forEach {
        tab(it) {
            label("Hello $it")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My pleasure :))